# What is wrong with my sorting function?

Tags: c, function, sorting

It doesn't seem to sort all the numbers. Some totally disappear.

```
void sort ()
{
    int i = 0, l = 0;

    while(i < myclass.d_arr_size)
    {
        if(myclass.d_arr[i] <= myclass.d_arr[l])
        {
            myclass.d_arr[i] = myclass.d_arr[l];
            i++;
        } else (l < myclass.d_arr_size) ? (l++) : (l=0, i++);
    }
}
```

---

What is wrong?

Comment: this => `} else (l < myclass.d_arr_size) ? (l++) : (l=0, i++);` may be a source of mistakes and is not friendly. Keep your code simple to read, it'll be simple to debug

Comment: In your `if` statement, you set the value at `myclass.d_arr[i]` to `myclass.d_arr[l]`, but then nothing seems to happen to the original value of `myclass.d_arr[i]`. This may be where the number elimination appears to happen.

Comment: Good read: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Sorry, but aren't you overwriting the data?

Comment: You forgot to debug it.

Comment: Another good read: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Use two `for` loops and a temporary variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
myclass.d_arr[i] = myclass.d_arr[l];
```

You should swap values instead of just assigning to the `i` index.

This may not be the sole bug in your code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()

{

    int x, y, a, l, number[30];

    printf("Enter the value of N \n");
    scanf("%d", &l);
    printf("Enter the numbers \n");
    for (x = 0; x < l; ++x)
        scanf("%d", &number[x]);
    for (x = 0; x < l; ++x)
    {
        for (y = x + 1; y < l; ++y)
        {
            if (number[x] > number[y])
            {
                a =  number[x];
                number[x] = number[y];
                number[y] = a;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The numbers arranged in ascending order are given below \n");
    for (x = 0; x< l; ++x)
        printf("%d\n", number[x]);
}
```

this code will be sort numbers in an ascending order